# Remove lines containg string followed by x number of numbers

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Hello I want to remove lines from a csv which contain the string `vol` followed by 2 or more number.

Examples data:

```
2454564, Stage Mechanics vol 4   8 9, 121545, 454545454
24545454, Dancing on ice vol 5, 454554, 45454545
5454545, Who is the man, 545456454, 4545454
8785648654, year of the Panda vol 89 12, 545454, 545454
```

Desired Output:

```
24545454, Dancing on ice vol 5, 454554, 45454545
5454545, Who is the man, 545456454, 4545454
```

I know I can use:

```
cat $csv1 | grep -vi "vol" > $newcsv
```

but obviously this would just remove lines with "vol" in- how do I incorporate the followed by 2 or more numbers rule to this code?

Thanks

Comment: `grep -vi 'vol [[:digit:]]{2}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this grep:

```
grep -Ev '\bvol([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2}' file

24545454, Dancing on ice vol 5, 454554, 45454545
5454545, Who is the man, 545456454, 4545454
```

Pattern `([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2}` will match at least 2 numbers separated by space/tab after `vol`.

Comment: You got that right.  My pattern doesn't address the `Stage Mechanics` line.

Comment: Just added a new question which relates to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143780/generate-record-of-files-which-have-been-removed-by-grep-as-a-secondary-function