# Generate record of files which have been removed by grep as a secondary function of primary command

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I asked a question here to remove unwanted lines which contained strings which matched a particular pattern:

[Remove lines containg string followed by x number of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105511/remove-lines-containg-string-followed-by-x-number-of-numbers)

anubhava provided a good line of code which met my needs perfectly. This code removes any line which contains the string `vol` followed by a space and three or more consecutive numbers:

```
grep -Ev '\bvol([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2}' file > newfile
```

The command will be used on a fairly large csv file and be initiated by crontab. For this reason, I would like to keep a record of the lines this command is removing, just so I can go back to check the correct data that is being removed- I guess it will be some sort of log containing the name sof the lines that did not make the final cut. How can I add this functionality?

Comment: What about using `wc` for file line counting and `bc` for calculation?

Comment: `grep -E '\bvol([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2}' file > filtered.txt` will give you all the lines being filtered out

Comment: Ok,  I intended to simultaneously do both, but I guess you mean run this command first then the other one?

Comment: *"Am I allowed to update my perl script section now so that it makes more sense? Do other users have to ask advice to do this or just me?"* No, it's just you: three of us ganged up because we didn't like your username. What do you think? You posted a sloppy question without even testing the excerpt that you included, and then made two abortive attempts to rationalise it, which invalidated the work that others had done for you (for free) and *still* didn't make any sense. It would have been easy for you to create a proper example program that you *knew* would do what you said it did.

Comment: Get out of the wrong side of bed today Borodin? Your tone throughout stank, the one other persons was fine. Try meditating, it works for me. Peace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop grep and use awk instead:

```
awk '/\<vol([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2}/{print >> "deleted"; next} 1' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for word delimiters (`\<`) and will append every deleted line to a file named "deleted". Consider adding a timestamp too:

```
awk '/\<vol([[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+){2}/{print systime(), $0 >> "deleted"; next} 1' file
```

Comment: Extending this to also extract the non-matches to a different file at the same time will be fairly easy. Maybe you should add that.

Comment: Not sure I understand the suggestion. I think this is doing everything the OP wanted (only printing to stdout lines that do not match a given regexp and saving the lines that do match that regexp in a log file), not sure the value in adding yet another file or what it'd contain.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for a redirect but the result is simply being produced on stdout.